# Using generics in kotlin with star projection

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have the follow interface

```
sealed interface Resource<out T> {
    data class Success<T>(val data: T?) : Resource<T>
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : Resource<Nothing>
}
```

I am using it like this in a usecase

```
 suspend fun execute(fromLanguage: Language, fromText: String, toLanguage: Language): Resource<Any> {
        return try {
            val translatedText = translationClient.translate(...)
            Resource.Success(translatedText)
        }
        catch (translationException: TranslationException) {
            Resource.Error(translationException)
        }
    }
```

And I am using the result of that in a viewmodel

```
 val result = translateUseCase.execute(...)

                when(result) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        result.data
                    }

                    is Resource.Error -> {

                    }
                }
```

A couple of confusing things is it best to use either one for the return type:

The use case does return a String if it succeeds, so would this be better.

```
 suspend fun execute(fromLanguage: Language, fromText: String, toLanguage: Language): Resource<String>
```

Because if could return a error if a exception is thrown or String if its successful so in this case would Any be better

```
 suspend fun execute(fromLanguage: Language, fromText: String, toLanguage: Language): Resource<Any>
```

Or is it just better to use star projection

```
 suspend fun execute(fromLanguage: Language, fromText: String, toLanguage: Language): Resource<*>
```

What would be the best way to do this Response interface?

Comment: If I were your teammate I prefer to see method with exact type to avoid any confusion.
`Resource<String>` is better option since you don't expect to return resource of any other type, however I am not sure that the desing of `Resource` interface is correct

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that you force the Error type to Nothing. It should conform to the expected success : `data class Error<T>(throwable: Throwable) : Resource<T>`.

Comment: @Steyrix what would you do differently in designing the `Resource`?

Comment: @ant2009 comment above by amanin explains that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Resource<String>` is the most sensible return type. In this case, the type `String` is the type of the data if it's successful. Even if you have an `Error<String>`, this still contains more information than an `Error<Any>` because it tells you the error is the result of requesting a `String` specifically.

If you make the return type `Resource<Any>`, you are removing information without gaining any benefits. You wouldn't be able to retrieve a successful result as a String, and yet it would have no impact on how you work with it if it's an error. So there is only a disadvantage to doing this with no benefits in the case of an error.

Since `T` is `out`, a `Resource<*>` is the same as `Resource<Any>` in this case.

Comment: Just a quick question how is T is out the same as Resource<*>. Just interested to know more?

Comment: `Resource<*>` means we are being as vague as possible about what T is. However, no matter what the type is of what you’re retrieving, it can be upcast to `Any`. So when you have covariant T, `<*>` and `<Any>` mean exactly the same thing. This is explained in the official Kotlin generics documentation in the section about star projection.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, I don't really understand why you even consider not using `Resource<String>`. If our function returns `String`, but it may also throw an exception, that doesn't mean we change it to return `Any`. In your specific case `Resource<String>` means: "String value if successful, otherwise an exception". It provides a full and precise information about potential return types.

So the answer is: use `Resource<String>`.

Answer (score 2):

> `data class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : Resource<Nothing>`

Are you **really** returning a resource on error? And do you have a requirement to handle that error early in the flow?

Looking at your use case, the answer seems no. So I wonder if having a default failure handler interceptor, that thrown exceptions propagate to instead of manually catching those errors, would be a better approach?

However, if there is such requirement to handle those errors in a more structured and predictable way, have a look at [Arrow's typed errors](https://arrow-kt.io/learn/typed-errors/) as it seems that's what you're trying to achieve (i.e. `Either<Fail, Success>`)